# How to solve the CSScomb error in PhpStorm?

Tags: css, node.js, formatting, phpstorm

I wanted to install on PhpStorm 8.0.1 CSScomb.js
I do everything as it is written on a page on github. Established CSScomb globally and locally (so sure). Prescribed ways and...
...run and out this error:

> Error running CSScomb: Can not run program "C: \ Users \ Kanat \
>   AppData \ Roaming \ npm \ node_modules \ csscomb \ bin \ csscomb" (in
>   directory "D: \ OpenServer \ domains \ LPDevplate \ src \ scss \
>   modules"): CreateProcess error = 193% 1 is not a valid Win32
>   application

Someone faced with this error and help solve it?

Comment: "on a page on github" How about pointing us to that information?

Comment: The file you are trying to execute is a JS file. Most likely (similarly to other tools) the correct file should be `"C:\Users\Kanat\AppData\Roaming\npm\csscomb.cmd"`

Answer (score -1):

the same error "Error running 'CSScomb': Cannot run program"